# how to copy vscode folder without github repository

Tags: fork, branch, clone, pull-request, branching-and-merging

How to copy vocode folder without GitHub repository?

id like to better my code so i copied the project's folder but when i want to commit it to GitHub its automatically connected to the original project's repository.

how do i clone/duplicate a vs code project and commit it to a new GitHub repository?
thank you

i tried copying my project to make an original folder with it being the "safe" code that works, and make a copy to try and better my code without changing the original one and risk loosing all of my work.

Comment: You probably want to remove/change the repository’s remote reference. This might be a keyword to search for

Answer (score 0):

Git keeps the repository and local settings in a subfolder `.git` which is why when you copied the folder all settings got copied, too.

You can change the remote repository from within vscode via the settings in the `source control` panel -> `Remote` -> `Add/Remove Remote`

Or if you have git for the commandline:

```bash
git remote set-url origin <new-remote-url>
```